# Input date in dd-MMM-yy and output in a tuple of (y,m, d)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I also have to translate the month from, for example, FEB or MAR to it's number equivalent like 02 or 03. I have to use a dictionary to do this, and I've managed to do that but I can't finish it off. I also have to use a string operation to split the date in to 3 items using the "-" character. Here's what I've done so far:

```
month = { "JAN": "01", "FEB": "02", "MAR": "03", "APR": "04", "MAY": "05", "JUN": "06",      "JULY": "07", "AUG": "08", "SEP": "09", "OCT": "10", "NOV": "11", "DEC": "12"}


 date = raw_input("Enter the date")
 split(date,"-")
```

So ideally the date would be entered like:

```
22-MAR-95
```

and it would give out a tuple of:

```
(95, 02, 22)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module for a more efficient way of dealing with dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#get idealDate  
items = idealDate.split("-")
your_tuple =  (items[2],month[items[1]],items[0])
#convert from strings to ints if you wish
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at dateutil.parser.  This module has a nearly automagical way of turning any date format into a datetime object.  It hasn't failed me yet.